# How to draw a bitmap to a section of a Picture control?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I'm trying to draw a bitmap into a section of a CDC. I load the bmp, BitBlt the CDC with the bitmap information and nothing shows up, this is my code:

```
CWnd* pWindow = GetParent()->GetDlgItem(IDC_DIAGRAM);
CClientDC windowDC(pWindow);
CDC* CDC = windowDC;
// I draw the graph and other objects I need here, everything works perfectly so far

HANDLE hBitMap = ::LoadImage(0, L"Diagram.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
CBitmap bmp;
bmp.Attach((HBITMAP)hBitMap);
// For testing purposes I tried drawing this bmp into a separate picture control with the bmp property turned on and it drew fine, So i know the data is loaded properly.
CDC->SelectObject(bmp);
// start Position = (0,0) , width = 500, height = 500, imageStartPos = (0,0)
CDC->BitBlt(0, 0, 500, 500, &CDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

After the following code nothing shows up, what im expecting is:

```
 _____________
|     |      |
| BMP |      |
|_____|      |
|            |
|    CDC     |
|            |
|            |
______________
```

Is there any way to do this without having to stack picture controls on top of each other?

edit: Got it to work, the working code is:

```
CDC* CDC = windowDC;
CDC* bmDC;
CClientDC dc(this);
// Load bmp the same way as above
bmDC->SelectObject(bmp);
bmDC->CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
CDC->BitBlt(0, 0, 500, 500, bmDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

Comment: You're using `BitBlt` incorrectly. You need to create a *second* compatible CDC and select your bitmap into that, then copy into your original CDC.

Comment: Perfect, creating a new compatible CDC, selecting the bitmap with the new CDC, and then calling `CDC->BitBlt(0,0,500,500, bmpCDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);` worked perfectly, thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad I could help! I only regret that I didn't have a code sample handy, otherwise I would have left a proper answer.